Unable to rotate the popup horizontally around the marker's axis
This is regarding the flutter_map plugin.I created a custom popup for my markers. However, when I rotate the map, the marker's rotation works fine, but the popup does not stay horizontally aligned on top of the marker. Instead, the rotation causes it to move all over the place.
This is the main class
class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  final CustomPopupController _popupController = CustomPopupController();

  final List<Marker> _markers = [
    const Marker(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      rotate: true,
      point: LatLng(44.421, 10.404),
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      child: Icon(Icons.location_on, size: 40),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Map with Marker Popups'),
      ),
      body: FlutterMap(
        options: const MapOptions(
          initialZoom: 5.0,
          initialCenter: LatLng(44.421, 10.404),
        ),
        children: [
          TileLayer(
            urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          ),
         
          CustomPopupMarkerLayerWidget(
            options: CustomPopupMarkerLayerOptions(
              markers: _markers,
              popupController: _popupController,
              popupBuilder: (BuildContext context, Marker marker) => Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('Popup for marker at ${marker.point}'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is the CustomPopup classs
class CustomPopupController {
  void Function()? _hideAllPopups;

  void hideAllPopups() {
    if (_hideAllPopups != null) {
      _hideAllPopups!();
    }
  }

  void setHideAllPopupsCallback(void Function() callback) {
    _hideAllPopups = callback;
  }
}

class CustomPopupMarkerLayerOptions {
  final List<Marker> markers;
  final CustomPopupController? popupController;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, Marker marker) popupBuilder;

  CustomPopupMarkerLayerOptions({
    required this.markers,
    this.popupController,
    required this.popupBuilder,
  });
}

class CustomPopupMarkerLayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final CustomPopupMarkerLayerOptions options;

  const CustomPopupMarkerLayerWidget({super.key, required this.options});

  @override
  _CustomPopupMarkerLayerWidgetState createState() =>
      _CustomPopupMarkerLayerWidgetState();
}

class _CustomPopupMarkerLayerWidgetState
    extends State<CustomPopupMarkerLayerWidget> {
  Marker? _selectedMarker;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.options.popupController?.setHideAllPopupsCallback(() {
      setState(() {
        _selectedMarker = null;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final map = MapCamera.of(context)!;

    return MobileLayerTransformer(
      child: Stack(
        children: widget.options.markers.map((marker) {
          final pxPoint = map.project(marker.point);
          final pos = pxPoint - map.pixelOrigin.toDoublePoint();

          return Positioned(
            key: marker.key,
            width: marker.width,
            height: marker.height,
            left: pos.x - marker.width / 2,
            top: pos.y - marker.height / 2,
            child: Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..translate(marker.width / 2, marker.height / 2)
                ..rotateZ(-map.rotationRad)
                ..translate(-marker.width / 2, -marker.height / 2),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_selectedMarker == marker) {
                      _selectedMarker = null;
                    } else {
                      _selectedMarker = marker;
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: marker.child,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList()
          ..addAll(_buildPopups(context)),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Positioned> _buildPopups(BuildContext context) {
    if (_selectedMarker == null) return [];

    final map = MapCamera.of(context)!;
    final pxPoint = map.project(_selectedMarker!.point);
    final pos = pxPoint - map.pixelOrigin.toDoublePoint();

    return [
      Positioned(
        left: pos.x,
        top: pos.y - 50,
        child: Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..translate(-pos.x, -pos.y)
            ..rotateZ(map.rotationRad)
            ..translate(pos.x, pos.y),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: widget.options.popupBuilder(context, _selectedMarker!),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }
}

